# Accessing an environment variable with ENV inside a quoted string is not working

Tags: environment-variables, jq

```
cat /home/azure/fourkeys/deploy.json |jq  '.value[]|  "build, \(.id), \(.startTime), \(.finishTime)"'
"build, 7765709, 2023-12-05T09:19:44.8090261Z, 2023-12-05T09:23:11.4171119Z"
```

I wish to replace build with shell variables.

```
 export name="build"
```

I tried to pass shell variable in cli, didn't work as below:

```
cat /home/azure/fourkeys/deploy.json |jq  '.value[]|  "$ENV.name, \(.id), \(.startTime), \(.finishTime)"'
"$ENV.name, 7765709, 2023-12-05T09:19:44.8090261Z, 2023-12-05T09:23:11.4171119Z"
```

json file:

```json
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 7765709,
      "buildNumber": "20231205.2",
      "status": "completed",
      "result": "succeeded",
      "queueTime": "2023-12-05T09:19:39.1877578Z",
      "startTime": "2023-12-05T09:19:44.8090261Z",
      "finishTime": "2023-12-05T09:23:11.4171119Z",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/slb1-swt/68bde508-a9d3-43ca-ae50-1ad38b747a65/_apis/build/Builds/7765709"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us the json file

Comment: posted json file

Comment: I don't see an error in your use of `$ENV`. What happens if you - just for debugging - replace the `$ENV.name` by `build`. Does it work then?

Comment: btw, in general `cat file.json | jq ...` is less efficient than `<file.json jq ...` or `jq ... file.json`, because it's starting two separate processes (`cat` and `jq`) instead of just one (`jq` alone). Doubly true when instead of jq you're using something like `tail` or `sort` or `wc -c` that has optimizations it can perform _only_ when given a seekable file handle.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing is because of using `$ENV` or `env` inside double-quotes, which is [interpolated as a string](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) in `jq` and its value is emitted out literally. You need to use them inside single quotes or use the syntax for expression evaluation i.e. `\(..)`

```bash
jq '.value[] | "\($ENV.name), \(.id), \(.startTime), \(.finishTime)"'
```

or) store the value in a temporary variable and evaluate it inside the double-quotes.

```bash
jq '$ENV.name as $v | .value[] | "\($v), \(.id), \(.startTime), \(.finishTime)"'
```